# 'DefaultCatalog' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Plus several similar errors

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to connect to a database on my LocalDB SQLEXPRESS server.  I have found the code on another forum which according to the author is probabily an overkill. 
All of the code I used can be found on this GitHub link:
https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/DataGridViewConfiguration/tree/master/TeamLibrary
The files I have used are: Class `BaseExceptionProperties`, Class `BaseSqlSrverConnections` and `dataOperations`.
My code attached to the form1 is as follows:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private dataOperations As New DataOperations
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Dim dtCustomers = dataOperations.LoadCustomers()
        If ***dataOperations.IsSuccessFul*** Then
            ' do something with dtCustomers
        Else
            MessageBox.Show($"Encountered a problem, ***{dataOperations.LastExceptionMessage}")***
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

The highlighted text says that it is not a member of dataOperations!
Also the following in the dataOperation class are saying that they are not declared or may be inaccessable due to their protection level:
`DefaultCatalog`
`ConnectionString`
`mHasException`
`mLastException`

Surely because of the fact that the classes are inherited by default, by each class, they should not need declaring?  I am not experienced enough to know about protection levels, so is this the case?

Comment: Karen Payne is good at answering question directly on her code. She is a member here on Stack Overflow but does not participate often. She can be found on the Microsoft boards. Check the object browser for what is where in her classes.

Answer (score 0):

The properties you mention are defined in the class `BaseExceptionsHandler` in the github repository. Did you forget to include that one in your project?

Comment: Yes that class is in my project, its called by BaseSqlServerConnections, which in turn is called by DataOperations.

Comment: The `DataOperations` class in the repository does not contain a `LoadCustomers` method. Did you write that yourself? If so can you show the code?